# Looking for a science fiction short story called "The Pacer"

Tags: story-identification, christian

The story I read back in the mid-late 70's was in a two or three-parter in Christian magazine, but the story itself did not have religious themes, per se.

The main story was about a group of space academy cadets in a ship.  Our hero is an idealistic man and his best friend, both who are cadets on the ship.  What's also common knowledge is that one of the cadets is a "pacer" ... a cyborg who is placed there to maintain the high competitive edge and push the the real cadets to be their very best.  And it's a common belief amongst the cadets each year, that you must find and kill the cyborg or your class is cursed.

Something goes wrong and the ship's computer loses it's ability to pilot the ship.  The commandant asks for a volunteer to help with the navigational computations.  Everybody knows that it's very likely going to be the pacer who volunteers.

So our hero's best friend steps forward and the rest of the story is about the other cadets encouraging him to do some snooping, get proof his friend is the pacer, and then help kill him.  The hero is torn.

... on the other hand, maybe there ARE religious themes  lol!  Anyway, I'd love to know the author so I can track down this story and read it again.

Thanks all !

Comment: pacer? its call the fitness gram pacer test*

Comment: Yup The Answer -  that has to be it.  I will go find it.  Thanks!

Comment: Pacer by Raymond F. Jones (from Future Kin, © 1974) Summary: A class of futuristic space cadets must decide whether to accept a member whom they suspect to be a robot known as the Pacer or to follow tradition and kill him.